# DotNetNuke Multivendor CMS/Store

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I need to find a CMS like, set of modules/module which does the following:

- give users different logins and access to add their own products.
- other users cannot see products which are not added by themselves.

so user A can enter his login and add a set of 5 products.  user B can enter his login and add 2 products.  user A can never see the 2 products added by B and vice versa.

Any suggestion in already existing modules? 
both free and with a price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Forms and Lists. Setup the fields you want to collect and then you can use it to only render the logged in users results to them. Also could use XMLdb module or even reports module to query the data out of the database after saved with forms and lists

Answer (score 0):

So no one can see each others products? They are just going to buy from themselves? ;)

Tricky part about users adding their own products is payment. That's why this is not a common store feature. If you allow people to add products, you usually need to allow them to setup their own payment provider to collect the money. And in some cases you (the site owner) would want to take a percentage. Which makes it even more complicated.

I'm not aware of any GOOD DotNetNuke e-commerce module that can do this.

It's very possible [Catalook](http://www.dnnsoft.com/) has some feature to do this. They have somehow tried to add every feature ever imagined into their product. But, overall I find it terrible to work with. That is your best bet for trying to get something like that out of the box.

Or try and get one of the open source solutions like NBstore and modify it.

Comment: there will be no payment involved, this is not going to be an ecommerce website but will be very similar in certain ways, such as having manufacturers and products. products can be seen by a group of people without knowing who the manufacturer is.